# Python: random 10 ms delays in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, time

If I execute this code:

```
 def test():
  k = 0
  t = time.time()
  times = []

  for i in range(500):
      for j in range(500):
          k+=1
          t1 = time.time()-t
          t2 = time.time()-t
          times.append(t2-t1)
  return times
```

and plot the delays, I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRaES.png). There seem to be 10 millisecond delays every so often. I noticed this when running another program where those spikes made up most of the execution time.

So, what causes these delays? Removing the time function does reduce the execution time but in other slower functions, it doesn't impact execution time enough to be the cause of the spikes.

Here is another function, where the same spikes appear but are much more regular

```
def search(img, pos, rad):
   t = time.time()

   times = []

   pos_tot = np.array([0,0]).astype(float)
   lum_tot = 0
   k = 1
   for i in range(max(pos[0]-rad, 0), min(pos[0]+rad+1, img.shape[0])):
       for j in range(max(pos[1]-rad, 0), min(pos[1]+rad+1, img.shape[1])):
           t1 = time.time()

           k+=1

           lum = int(((img[i][j][0] + img[i][j][0] + img[i][j][0])/3/30)**3) 

           pos_tot+= np.array([i,j]).astype(float)*lum

           t2 = time.time()-t
           times.append(t2-t1)

   return times
```

the times look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2nz4.png), appearing approximately every 71 iterations.

Could this be OS related (Windows 10)? If it is, how could I avoid these delays?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: list resizing when doing `times.append(t2-t1)` ?

Comment: time is a system call. It consumes some resources. You cannot use that in a very fast loop without some overhead.

Comment: It isn't the list resizing since printing instead of appending a list will yield the same result. If is it the time call, why are the delays not occuring at every iteration?